# Looking for a client portal/dashboard alternative to communities

Tags: community, customer-portal, appexchange

Communities seems to be geared both in price and feature set for large enterprise. As a very small business, I am wondering if there is an alternative to communities for creating/displaying a personalize dynamic dashboard for my clients?

Please let me know if more details are required to answer this question. I will likely be using Rethinkcrm or Propertybase but I expect this solution will be outside this.  I also expect some custom dev work.

Any direction will be great appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Derek